# How to randomly display multiple videos via one image target

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to display a random video from a group of videos each time the AR camera recognizes the marker. I know you can recognize multiple markers but I want to display a different video each time you tap the screen or each time it recognizes the marker (say you look away and then turn back towards it).

I tried adding more than one video to the image marker, but theres only space for one video.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Solution :
first, add all the videos as children to the image target

in OnTrackinFound event try this :
1- generate a random index between 0 and the length of your videos then 
Enable the Child object with this random index number and disable the others.
2- in OnTrackingLost event setActive(false) for all the Image target children.

Answer (score 0):

Create a GameObject called **VideoController**. In the VideoController create a **List of MovieTexture** and add your videos to the list. Create a **Plane** with **VideoPlayer** component as a child of the ImageTarget.

In the **DefaultTrackableEventHandler** component of Image Target, look for a function called **OnTrackingFound**. It is called when Image Target is detected. Use native C# random function or Unity's **Random.Range** function to generate a random number **between 0 and (n-1)th item** of the list. Use that value to add Video Texture to the Plane.

Read more here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html

Let me know if you run into any problem.